# How can I resolve the ReferenceError regarding TextDecoder not being defined while testing with Create React App using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to run the following test but it is throwing an error for some reason. If I disable it the tests run OK.

```
describe('getFirebaseStorageAvailableNames', () => {
  it('should return "1" when the array is empty', () => {
    const arr: string[] = [];
    expect(getFirebaseStorageAvailableNames(arr)).toBe('1');
  });

  it('should return the smallest available number as a string', () => {
    const arr: string[] = ['1', '2', '3'];
    expect(getFirebaseStorageAvailableNames(arr)).toBe('4');
  });
});
```

```
 FAIL  src/helpers/tests/firestoreHelpers.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: TextDecoder is not defined

      1 | // Firebase
      2 | import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    > 3 | import { browserSessionPersistence, getAuth, setPersistence } from 'firebase/auth';    
        | ^
      4 | import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
      5 | import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
      6 | import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fastify/busboy/lib/utils/decodeText.js:4:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fastify/busboy/lib/utils/parseParams.js:4:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fastify/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:15:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@fastify/busboy/lib/main.js:7:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js:3:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js:4:47)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/undici/index.js:119:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node/totp-e9be401a.js:7:14)        
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node/index.js:5:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/index.cjs.js:5:12)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/firebase/firebase.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/helpers/firesotreHelpers.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/helpers/tests/firestoreHelpers.test.ts:4:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 9 passed, 10 total
Tests: 150 passed, 150 total
```

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.12",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.12",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.12",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.45",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.65",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.21",
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the one from [node util](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#class-utiltextencoder).

For [create react app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/), put this in your `src/setupTests.js` file

```
import { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } from 'util';

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

Comment: the issue is create react app is pre configuring the jest, and I don't want to mess with the basic setup. any instructions on how to safely extend the default setup. so technically I don't have any files in my root.

Comment: Ah, create-react-app, use [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco) - it's a drop in replacement and the only thing you have to do is to modify the [jest configuration](https://craco.js.org/recipes/use-a-jest-config-file/)

Comment: so in this case  where should i put the import { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } from 'util';

Comment: Actually @Richardson, I just re-read the [CRA docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/) (it's been a while) and you don't need to use craco, you can just use `src/setupTests.js`, I've edited my answer to specify to put the contents in `src/setupTests.js`